# hook for postprocessing a field realtime with gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm wanting to implement a validation check on a mobile phone number field using gravity forms. I've got all of the bits together, but just need an idea on how to trigger the sending of an SMS to that number when the field is exited. I was hoping just to use a gform_field_validation_form_field filter, using the Real Time Validation for Gravity Forms plugin, but it doesn't look like it works that way.

Does anyone know how to do some basic server side processing once a field is filled in (and exited?) ??

Comment: what do you mean with "when the field is exited"?

Comment: Add content to field ( eg phone number ), then leave the field to move on to the next one.